# Is it possible to have indexes for like '%*%' type queries

Tags: query, index, sql-server-2008-r2

Now for my thesis project i need to make a lot of queries like the below

```
select * from tblMyTable where ItemName like '%item%'
```

Now my question : is that possible to create indexes for such queries ? If so what is the way of doing it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For LIKE queries this is not available.

But for making such queries SQL Server provides functionality called Full-text search. More info in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Comment: So when i set full-text search will i be able to still use the query above ? Or i need different format ?

Comment: You will need a different format and you will need to use Filltext-specific functions to achieve needed result. Also result will be language-specific to your database. Please refer to [MSDN: Querying SQL Server Using Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142559.aspx) for further information. I do understand that might be not what you're looking for but that's the best SQL Server can offer for handling such needs.

Answer (score 0):

index will work if you have something like

```
where ItemName like 'item%'
```

also contains works much faster than like, see this: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2280727/Microsoft-SQL-Server-70-Full-Text-Search-What-is-full-text-search